# How to access a variable inside when statement in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, switch-statement

I'm working on a self-assessment feature, that will enable people to know whether they are at risk of having been infected with corona or not hence advising them whether to get tested or not. I have created a number of radio group button to allow the patient to check different symptoms, for each clicked radio button is assigned which is supposed to be added together with other values so as to find a score upon which we can know whether the patient should proceed to covid-19 testing or not. I need help in fixing my code so that I can be able to read and add all the values of each radio button. Here is my code.

```
if (view is RadioButton) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        val checked = view.isChecked

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        when (view.getId()) {
            R.id.yes_1 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val yes1= 1
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            R.id.no_1 ->
                if (checked){
                    val no1=0
                    Toast.makeText(this, " No 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            R.id.yes_2 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val yes2= 1
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            R.id.no_2 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val no2= 0
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            R.id.yes_3 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val yes3=1
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            R.id.no_3 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val no3=0
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            R.id.yes_4 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val yes4=1
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            R.id.no_4 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val no4=0
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            R.id.yes_5 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val yes5=5
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            R.id.no_5 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val no5=0
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            R.id.yes_6 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val yes6=5
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Yes 6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            R.id.no_6 ->
                if (checked) {
                    val no6=0
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No 6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
        val assesment_point= yes1 + n01 + yes2 + no2 +yes3 + no3 + yes4 + no4 + yes5 + no5 + yes6 + no6
    }
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of how the app works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOIl2.png)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the [scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/declaring-variables.html#scopes-and-naming) defines if a variable can be accessed. In your case those vals only exist inside a when case block, not outside.

Quick fix could be to predefine them outside and change only the values inside the when block.

(offtopic: You misunderstood the [radio button sample](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) a bit. In your case you don't want to react on each radio button click but once a "submit" button is pressed. Also you don't need a "yes6" just a "answer6" which either gets "0" for no or a "1" for yes. That already would reduce the code complexity quite a bit...)